# Как создать массив с разным колличеством вложеных массивов

Tags: php

возникла необходимость создать двумерный  массив array() в котором мне нужно создавать разное количество массивов, то есть array(array(),array(),...,array())

количество вложенных массивов известно, но оно изменяется
и как их индексировать по типу 
array(1 =>array(),44 =>array(),...,xxx=>array())

мне нужно хранить данные вида:
то есть там хранятся оценки по навыкам людей и к ним нужно обращаться по id_человека и навыку

```
arr_ocenki[1][навык1]=43
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем суть проблемы? Если нужно, так храните как написали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = [
  'id1' => ['навык1' => 43, 'навык2' => 52, 'навык3' => 345, ...],
  'id2' => ['навык1' => 43, 'навык2' => 52, 'навык3' => 345, ...]
];

$arr['id1']['навык1'] = 43;
```

Как то так